# Transfer a D7 view sql query to a D9 view

Tags: drupal-views, sql, drupal-9

We are converting a number of D7 views (for reports) to D9 version.  Is it possible to copy the sql query from a D7 view to use in a D9 view.  The fields in Civi are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Now that the [Drupal Views Migration](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_migration) has been released it would be worth trying that, especially if you have several.

In terms of your actual question, I think the answer is No.

We have just started converting some d7 Views to D9 and as expected the 'relationship' (as in Views 'join') needs some manual intervention, especially for fields like Email, Address, Phone where those had been hard-coded in the d7 Views integration. But apart from that they came through in better shape than I expected.